# HTML/CSS Text Align Not Working

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code for text-align:

```
<strong>Status:</strong> <span style="color: #01DF3A;">Updated</span>
<span align="right" style="text-align: right;"><strong>TeamSpeak:</strong> ts.abendigo.org</span>
```

[image]

The first text `Status: Updated` should be on the left but the second part of the text `TeamSpeak: ts.abendigo.org` should be on the right side but using even both the deprecated `align="right"` with `style="text-align: right;"` seems to have no effect with `span`. They work fine with other tags like `div` but I want to keep both text on the same line.

Comment: could you add `float:right` to your second `span`?

Comment: Did you define a width to your span so the text has actually space to go to the right side?

Comment: span as an inline element does not  have width or height. You can turn it into a block level element using css 'display:inline-block' or 'inline:block' though.

Comment: either use float or display:block. choice is yours

Comment: Typo above: I meant 'display:block', not 'inline:block'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<span>` is an inline element. From the screenshot below you can see that its width is `188.859px` and that's the size of the text in it.

[image]

You must wrap the inline elements in a block element. I'd suggest this:

```css
.status {
  float: left;
}
.teamspeak {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="status">
  <strong>Status:</strong><span style="color: #01DF3A;">Updated</span>
</div>
<div class="teamspeak">
  <strong>TeamSpeak:</strong> ts.abendigo.org</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works correctly. I chose to not use classes and rather just use `style=` for both the `div`s. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

NB: this answer explains how block level vs inline elements work.

The `text-align` property only works on block elements. `<span>` is `inline`. You should use a `<div>` or `<p>`.

```
<strong>Status:</strong> <span style="color: #01DF3A;">Updated</span>
<div style="text-align: right;">
    <span><strong>TeamSpeak:</strong> ts.abendigo.org</span>
</div>
```

NB: You can set span to be a block element, but unless your HTML is fixed (generated by some other application) and you cannot change it, don't do that. Better keep to what is standard and use div or p.

```
span { display: block; }
```

To get a working solution you should use `float: right;` on the span. I don't see why you would need to use a `float:left;` on the other text.

Comment: I have a problem with this, it goes on a second line: http://i.imgur.com/zIv8VYO.png

Comment: My explanation was more about block level vs inline elements. You need to use float to get the second line displayed on the same height.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"> <strong>Status:</strong> 
<span class="left">Updated</span>
<span class="right">
<strong>TeamSpeak:</strong> ts.abendigo.org</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
text-align:left;
color: #01DF3A
}
.right {
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
<div>
  <strong>Status: </strong><span style="color: #01DF3A;">Updated</span>
  <span style="float:right">TeamSpeak: ts.abendigo.org</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use blocks or a table where is text-align property works on:

```
<strong>Status:</strong> <span style="color: #01DF3A;display:inline-block;width:45%">Updated</span><span align="right" style="text-align: right;display:inline-block;width:45%"><strong>TeamSpeak:</strong> ts.abendigo.org</span>

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Status:</strong> <span style="color: #01DF3A">Updated</span></td>
        <td style="text-align:right"><span align="right" style="text-align:right"><strong>TeamSpeak:</strong> ts.abendigo.org</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Try the fiddle: 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yc8cyg56/)

Comment: Using tables to do this is going back ten years. We don't do that anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below link

```
    .status{
       float:left
    }
   .team{
        float:right;
     }
```

[Fiddle - Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/z8wunbL7/)

Comment: please note that  when you are using float then you should use clear:both too or else you will get white space issue.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="status">
  <strong>Status:</strong><span style="color: #01DF3A;">&nbsp;Updated</span>
</div>
<div class="teamspeak">
  <strong>TeamSpeak:</strong> ts.abendigo.org</span>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.status {
  float: left;
}
.teamspeak {
  float: right;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/tkuqufev/1/)